# AWK command in bash program

Tags: bash, awk

here is my program:

```
for ((i=1;i<=300;i++)); do

  awk 'NR==$i{print}' file.dat > fileB.dat

done
```

the `file.dat` contains 300 lines that I want to save in different files, 
but the `NR==$i` doesn't work, nothing is printed.

I don't see what is wrong.
Thank you

Comment: Sorry I am confused: Do you want to generate a single file with one line or 300 files with different lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
for i in {1..300}; do
    awk "NR==$i{print}" file.dat > fileB.dat
done
```

The single quote ', prevents the shell from expanding variables, in this case `i`.

Comment: @EdMorton - well, dogbanes answer is much better, I just saw the error as a quoting issue and didn't think about it too much (I guess that's why he's a 70k rep user :-)

Comment: The error is not a quoting issue though, it's a thinking error in mistaking awk for shell. By changing the quoting you can force the $i to expand but then you open yourself up to backslash hell because then `$1` wouldn't mean `the 1st field in the current record` any more it'd mean `the first positional parameter in the shell command` so then you'd need to write `\$1` just to get the normal, expected awk functionality. To get the value of a shell variable inside an awk script, you use `-v i="$i"` or similar. There are other awk problems introduced too and yes, the shell loop is wrong too.

Answer (score 4):

Single quotes prevent expansion, so `$i` is not expanded into a number. Use double quotes instead.

However, instead of invoking `awk` multiple times in a loop, it's more efficient to use a single `awk` like this:

```
awk 'NR<=300 {print > NR".dat"}' file.dat
```

This will write each line to a different file.

Comment: +1 for the right answer but it needs to be `print > (NR".dat")` as it's ambiguous without the parens.